# How do i rename duplicate elements in python list of lists based on vertical position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
listofLists = [
                ['a', 'b', 'e'],
                ['a', 'd'],
                ['a', 'c'],
                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'],
                ['a', 'e', 'c', 'f']
                ]
```

How can i read this element list vertically and rename duplicates appending numbers to the element in incremental order? The output list has to preserve the same order.

For example, first position of 'e' is at index 1 in list ['a', 'e', 'c', 'f'], it should remain as it is. Next position of 'e' is at index 2 in list ['a', 'b', 'e'] which should be renamed as 'e1'. The last position of 'e' is in list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'] which should be renamed as 'e3'

The required output should be:

```
requiredOutput = [['a', 'b', 'e1'],
                  ['a', 'd'],
                  ['a', 'c'],
                  ['a', 'b', 'c1', 'e2'],
                  ['a', 'e', 'c1', 'f']]
```

The code i have tried is as below, by checking against a transposed list. But it does not give me the required output since my code changes the current element of the list. I dont know if this is the right approach to the problem statement.

```
transformedListOfTuples = list(zip_longest(*listofLists))
transformedListOfList= [list(x) for x in transformedListOfTuples]
for i in range(0, len(listofLists)):
    for j in range(0, len(listofLists[i])):
        pos = -1
        for z in range(0, len(transformedListOfList)):
            if listofLists[i][j] in transformedListOfList[z]:
                pos = pos + 1
                if pos == 0:
                    continue
                elif pos > 0:
                    listofLists[i][j] = listofLists[i][j] + str(pos)
            elif listofLists[i][j] not in transformedListOfList[z]:
                continue
```

Comment: Why are there 2 `c1`s?

Comment: because it is at the same position vertically. the two c1 has to be named so since the first 'c' is in index 1 in list ['a', 'c']

Comment: I hate to say this, but it looks like you are doing something wrong. Can you explain what you are actually trying to do - I.e. what is your purpose in doing this?

Using a uniquifier that depends upon a list position seems like you are mangling structure, which you will then be forced to decode later on.

Comment: @kederrac, I believe you may be missing my point - which is the 'why' of it, not the 'what' of it. My gut tells me that jay747 is not using the correct approach for what he is trying to do. I believe he is encoding position (structure) with his data, which violates several good rules of thumb.

Comment: @kederrac, comments are not suitable for discussions, but I am sure you know the difference between purpose and execution. I can see someone asking me how to jump off a cliff, but it doesn't tell me why they want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
arr = [
    ['a', 'b', 'e'],
    ['a', 'd'],
    ['a', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'],
    ['a', 'e', 'c', 'f']
]

listOfRepeated = []
max_len = 0

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    if max_len < len(arr[i]):
        max_len = len(arr[i])

for j in range(0, max_len):
    list_to_add = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if j < len(arr[i]):
            val = arr[i][j]
            # For each iteration of `i`, you'll go down the group

            if not val in list_to_add:
                list_to_add.append(val)
            
            count = listOfRepeated.count(val)
            if count > 0:
                arr[i][j] = ""+str(val)+""+str(count)

    for element in list_to_add:
        listOfRepeated.append(element)

for list in arr:
    print(list)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'e1']
['a', 'd']
['a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c1', 'e2']
['a', 'e', 'c1', 'f']
```

## Explanation:

`j` is the counter to go horizontally, `i` is the counter to go down the group. Every element is present at `arr[i][j]`

`list_to_add` is a list that contains every unique character for a particular group

`listOfRepeated` is a list of every element that has been seen so far. If you're present in listOfRepeated once, that means your current group is the first one with the character. If it is more than once, that means you need to add a number after the character.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
previous = {}
for i in range(max(len(e) for e in listofLists)):
    col = [l[i] for l in listofLists if len(l) > i]
    previous.update({e: previous.get(e, 0) + 1 for e in set(col)})

    for l in listofLists:
        if len(l) > i:
            if previous[l[i]] > 1:
                l[i] = l[i] + str(previous[l[i]] - 1)
listofLists
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'e1'],
 ['a', 'd'],
 ['a', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c1', 'e2'],
 ['a', 'e', 'c1', 'f']]
```

how it works: `previous` dict will store the current  number of occurrences of an element per columns, the first `for` loop iterate over all columns, at each iteration step the `previous` dict it is updated base on the elements from the current column, the inner `for` loop will update each element from the current column if the number of occurrences per columns is more than 1

or you can use:

```
from itertools import accumulate, zip_longest
from collections import Counter

cols = list(zip_longest(*listofLists))
t = [[f'{e}{a[e] - 1}' if e and a[e] > 1 else e for e in i] for i, a in
     zip(cols, accumulate((Counter(set(l)) for l in cols)))]
listofLists = [[e[i] for e in t if e[i]] for i in range(len(t[0]))]
```

you operate per column and get the transpose of your desired output (this is `t`)